# the right way to change the associated object in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, let

I recently started to test with rspec, so I can strongly be mistaken, correct me if there is a better way

I create two related models

```
let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create :user} 
let!(:participation) {FactoryGirl.create :participation, user: user}
```

and before one of the tests change one of the related objects

```
context "when" do
  before {participation.prize = 100}
  it "" do
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

But inside it

```
participation.prize => 100
user.participatons.select(:prize) => nil
```

what am I doing wrong ? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say `user.participations.select(:prize)`, you're making a query to the db to get values in the user's participations' prize columns. But when you say `before {participation.prize = 100}` you're only setting the prize *attribute* on the participation object. Try saving the participation before the select line:

```
participation.prize # => 100
participation.save
user.participatons.select(:prize) # => nil
```

Another possible issue is that `user.participations` has been memoized by a previous call. Ensure that `user.participations.first == participation`. If it doesn't, check

1) `puts participation.user_id` and

2) `puts user.participations, user.reload.participations`

---

Lastly, a better way of setting up the test so that you run into this issue less often is something along the lines of:

```
# let(:price) { 0 } # default price. Optional so that tests won't throw errors if you forget to set it in a context/describe block.
let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create :user} 
let!(:participation) {FactoryGirl.create :participation, user: user, price: price}

# ...

context "when ..." do
  let(:price) { 100 }
  it "" do
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

This way, the price is set *when you create the model*. Following this pattern generally means running into this problem less.